# Gitlab smtp email notifications not sending

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque, gitlab, sidekiq

GitLab should automatically send email to a new user with new generated password but he doesn't.
There are no errors in logs except for the sidekiq warning:

```
'WARN: Couldn't find User with id=10'
```

The database connection is OK. I've found a sidekiq [issue](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Problems-and-Troubleshooting#cannot-find-modelname-with-id12345) about this warning but it shouldn't crash email sending at all.
I have a suggestion that cause of the problem may be Resque gem wich as I understand have to handle Sidekiq queues.
If I try this command:

```
'sudo -u git bundle exec rake environment resque:work RAILS_ENV=production PIDFILE=./resque.pid QUEUE=runner --trace'
```

I get this error:

```
  rake aborted! 
  Don't know how to build task 'resque:work'
```

And also I found that there is no PID file gitlab/tmp/pids.
If I try this: 
    'stat -c %U resque_worker.pid '
I get this:

```
'stat: cannot stat `resque_worker.pid': No such file or directory'
```

Even if I set wrong login/password in config/initializers/smtp_settings.rb there is now auth errors so app not even trying to send emails.

How can I fix email sending in Gitlab?